# PoS quantum migration

Tags: staking

I have a slightly futuristic question. If there were QCs capable of breaking EC signatures (incl. BLS) and there were safe alternatives (ie ZK-STARKS), would it be possible to migrate staked ETH on the fly? I suppose each staker would have to manually move the coins, but would it be possible to do this without the validation process getting stuck-paused-endangered?

Sub-question: is there a discussion what to do with lost coins (vulnerable addresses with revealed PKs) - would they be stolen by QCs or get frozen by consensus after a multi-year deadline?

Comment: Sure. I imagine it would take a hard-fork, which is how the protocol is upgraded, and has been upgraded many times in the past.

Comment: Probably un-migrated addresses would get frozen by consensus when it seemed like someone was going to be able to break them.

Comment: @user253751 sure but every person would need to manually move the coins to a new safe address, is that right? That means a part of the coins would be at some point on BLS addresses, the other upgraded part on (e.g.) ZK-STARK addresses. I was curious how exactly would the validation continue with this scenario (before all staked coins are migrated).

Comment: probably exactly the same but with some extra code to handle both types of addresses